# Sinatra Variables in HTML Email Template

Tags: ruby, email, sinatra, sendmail

I have a working contact form sending in Sinatra. I am now trying to use a HTML template to send email but I can't get my variables working, they are just displaying as plain text. Here is code.

```
# for contact form
def send_message
  senders_name = params[:name]
  senders_email = params[:email]
  senders_message = params[:message]

  Mail.deliver do
    to 'me@mywebsite.com'
    from senders_name + " <" + senders_email + ">"
    subject 'Email from contact form on Website'
    # body senders_message
    html_part do
      content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
      body File.read('views/contact_form.erb')
    end
  end
end
```

On "views/contact_form.erb"...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>pygo Contact Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Message from <strong><%= senders_name %></strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= senders_message %>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The form sends and everything works fine except when email is delivered the variables read as "<%= senders_name %>" instead of actual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.read` will only return the literal value of the file, not the ERB-parsed version. That's why you're seeing the ERB tags in the email body instead of what you want.

In addition, there's a problem here that isn't your fault. Because of the  way `Mail.deliver` overrides the context of the block with it's own `self` for "convenience", you can't access instance variables or Sinatra methods like you normally should be able to. And that's why you're getting the `NoMethodError`.

The way to get around this is to render the Sinatra template outside of the `Mail.deliver` block, and pass in the variables as locals, like so:

```
def send_message
  senders_name = params[:name]
  senders_email = params[:email]
  senders_message = params[:message]

  html_body = erb :contact_form, locals: { senders_name: senders_name, senders_message: senders_message }

  Mail.deliver do
    to 'me@mywebsite.com'
    from senders_name + " <" + senders_email + ">"
    subject 'Email from contact form on Website'
    # body senders_message
    html_part do
      content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
      body html_body
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply brainbag. When I do it that way I get the following error in terminal..."NoMethodError - undefined method `erb' for #<Mail::Part:0x007f85ee0ba6c8>:"

Comment: Where is your `send_message` method defined? `erb` is a Sinatra method and will only be available in that context.

Comment: I am defining it inside my main app file "class AppController < Sinatra::Base .... end"

Comment: @polarcare check out the answer now - it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Yeah that did the job, thanks a million for the help brainbag!